# how to get the Variable name  in this file using python 

Tags: python, dictionary

this is the a.txt:

```
    attackUp = [10, 15]
    defenceUp = [10, 15]
    magicUp = [10, 15]
    attType = [1, 1]
    weightDown = [10, 15]

    #装饰器数据
    accAttackSword = [100, 100]
    accAttackSaber = [100, 100]
    accAttackAx = [100, 100]
    accAttackHammer = [100, 100]
    accAttackSpear = [100, 100]
    accAttackFight = [100, 100]

    accAttackBow = [100, 100]
    accAttackMagicGun = [100, 100]
    accAttackMagic = [100, 100]
    mStrInstrument = [100, 100]
    mStrCharms = [100, 100]
    accDefencePhy = [100, 100]
    accDefenceMag = [100, 100]
    accWeight = [100, 90, 0,0, 100, 90]

    #战术书数据
    bookTurn = [1, 1]
    bookAttackPhy = [100, 100]
    bookAttackMag = [100, 100]
    bookStrInstrument = [100, 100]
    bookStrCharms = [100, 100]
    bookDefencePhy = [100, 100]
    bookDefenceMag = [100, 100]
    bookWeight = [100, 100]

    #数据
    data = self.owner.get_user_info()
    npc = self.create_npc()
    name = [self.owner.name,'npc_1']
    plvl = [data.get('level'),npc.get('level')]
    str = [data.get('power'),npc.get('power')]
    ski = [data.get('skill'),npc.get('skill')]
    mag = [data.get('magic'),npc.get('magic')]
    spd = base.get('speed')[:2]
    locX = base.get('locX')
    locX = [locX[1],locX[4]]
    locY = base.get('locY')
    locY = [locY[1],locY[4]]
    wName = []; wAttack = []; wDefence = []; wWeight = [];wType = []; target = []
```

i want to get a dict like this :

```
{'attackUp':attackUp,'defenceUp':defenceUp,'magicUp':magicUp ...}
```

this is my code:

```
a=open('a.txt', 'rb')
a=a.read()
```

waht can i do ,

thanks

**updated:**

i use this code :

```
with open('a.txt', 'rb') as f:
    contents = f.read().decode('utf-8-sig')

items = {  }
for line in contents.split('\n'):
    item = line.split('=')[0].strip()
    items[item] = item

b=open('b.txt','wb')
b.write(unicode(items))
```

but it show :

```
{u'': u'', u'accDefencePhy': u'accDefencePhy', u'mStrCharms': u'mStrCharms', ..}
```

i want to get

```
{ 'accDefencePhy': accDefencePhy, 'mStrCharms': mStrCharms, ..}
```

so how to delete the `'` and `u`

Comment: What do you want in the dict for "plvl", etc.? Your file seems to contain Python code...

Comment: So you want a dictionary that somehow doesn't contain values, but variable names (but not as strings)? This is impossible. A dictionary can only contain objects... Unless you happen to have `accDefencePhy` etc. in scope in your code and you want their values to be injected into the dictionary

Answer (score 1):

Provided that you remove the `self.*` "variables" from your file (Python does not know how to make sense of them), you can get a dictionary that contains what you want with:

```
import a  # This supposes that your file is named a.py instead of a.txt

var_dict = vars(a)

print var_dict['accDefencePhy']  # Yields [100, 100]
```

(You also get a few additional entries in var_dict (namely `__doc__`, etc.), which you can remove if need be, after copying the original dictionary with `var_dict = vars(a).copy()`.)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just turn that txt file into a .py file and import it into the modules you want to use the values in?

instead of

attackup = chardict['attackup']

import charattrs

attackup = charattrs.attackup